# How to lunch Google Map app from a react native app with a direction as coordinates

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I am drawing a polyline on the MapView component from an array of coordinates that I am fetching from my backend server. There is a case when I want the user to open the installed Google Map on their android device with these coordinates and get directions based on that.

I know how to open the Google Map app with a single coordinate, like the following one:

```
const url = 'geo:37.484847,-122.148386';
Linking.openURL(url);
```

But, I am not sure (even have no idea if it is possible at all) how would I lunch the Google Map app with a bunch of coordinates and show them as a direction route (blue line).

As an example, If I have 3 points: A, B and C, I want to open the Google Map app and the app should display a direction route made using A to B and B to C.

Answer (score 1):

Just got my answer. Sharing it in case anyone else face the same problem.

We just need to open this url: `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&parameters` with the right parameters. In this case, waypoints. A collection of coordinates need to be passed using the pipe - `|` operator as the separator. The `lat` and `lon` should be separated by a comma.

Google has this documented here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action

Answer (score 1):

Great. To get the directions by deep linking you need to hit the API with the params as `origin` and `destination` . So check this `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&parameters` and in place of params you can replace it with the proper params.

Google has perfectly documented here, [google map direction](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action)

Hope it helps . feel free for doubts.